# klocwork reports issues with concatenation in a loop

Tags: c#

String concatenation in a loop. I get this bug when i tested my project in klocwork. i am concatenating many strings  in loop is it a big mistake .

```
for(int j=0;j<nAttr;j++)
{
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    size=rnd.Next(1,10);
    for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
    {
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(26 * rnd.NextDouble() + 65)) ;
        if(ch=='[' || ch==']')
            j--;
        else
            builder.Append(ch); 
    }
    strXml+=" "+builder.ToString();//here the bug arises 
    strXml+="="+"\"";
```

i also found this bug  when i tested

Class/struct data member is hidden by a local variable  what does it mean

```
private void TraverseValues(XmlNode n,ArrayList arr)
{
    if(n.HasChildNodes )
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<n.ChildNodes.Count;i++)
        {
            if(n.ChildNodes[i].Name=="#text")
                arr.Add(n.ChildNodes[i].InnerText );
            else    
                TraverseValues(n.ChildNodes[i],arr)//here the code arises
```

i completed my project .it works fine then i tested my product with klocwork it suggested these bugs .but i am not able to understand y it says it has critical error in code

Comment: I really have no idea what you are asking, please be more specific: What bug, when does it occur, expected output/actual output, some code...

Comment: Need more information, but I very much doubt you found such a basic bug in C# that the hordes of MS testers and users have not yet discovered.

Comment: We need some code, and I agree with Pax - there's probably just a bug in your code.

Comment: i think i have given the code

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It seems as if the code is supposed to create randomly sized random strings and concatenate them to strXml. What is the expected behaviour and what happens in reality?

Comment: You also need to specify what the first error was - you've only told us the first.

Comment: You should take out your second question to another thread to avoid confusity

Comment: i have just added a snippet of my project where i got the bugs. I got these bugs when i tested my project using klocwork, "String concatenation in a loop" and "Class/struct data member is hidden by a local variable". What those bugs actually mean.? What wromg with my code.

Comment: What bug? What is the problem? You're post is akin to saying "There's something wrong with my car, please fix it". We need to know what the problem is, what you are experiencing and what you expected to happen!

Comment: Voted down. It looks like you pasted the error from klocwork here without investigating what the problem might be and without knowing what actually goes wrong (if anything)

Comment: Somebody should add a klocwork tag to this question.

Comment: i completed my project .it works fine then i tested my product with klocwork it suggested these bugs .but i am not able to understand y it says it has critical error in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Klickwork creates a static analysis application.

I think Arunachalam refers to some static analysis assertion as "bug".

When strXml is of string type then it would be possible that static analysis will show `strXml+=" "+builder.ToString();` as bad code (a "bug").

From the code posted it is definitely not bug in the core .NET Library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be defining a variable in your loop that has the same name as one in the class?

Comment: No, that would not be ambiguous.  You would have to refer to the instance variable by using 'this' in that scope.

Comment: He doesn't say it's saying it's ambiguous, it might just be a warning he's getting. Although it's not exactly clear.

Answer (score 0):

What type of Bug do you expect there to be? Could you post more of your code, so that we can se, what should come out of this operation?

I just scrapped your code into a new project, cleaned the code a little bit up, but it seems to work like expected.

```
StringBuilder builder;
            int nAttr = 5;
            int size;
            char ch;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for(int j=0;j<nAttr;j++)
            {
               builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.Append(" ");
                size=rnd.Next(1,10);
                    for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
                    {
                            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(26 * rnd.NextDouble() + 65)) ;
                            if(ch=='[' || ch==']')
                                    j--;
                            else
                                    builder.Append(ch); 
                    }
                builder.Append("=\"");
                Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
            }
```

One thing I do not understand is why do you use a StringBuilder, then concatenate the result of the StringBuilder with a literal to a new string and concatenate that again. You should use your StringBuilder to build the whole string, the export the result.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have

```
if (ch=='[' || ch==']')
  k--;
```

But even this doesn't make sense, since you will only get characters from 'A' to 'Z'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, it sounds like your tool is trying to tell you to only update `strXml` once:

```
builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int j=0;j<nAttr;j++)
{
    builder.Append(" ");
    size=rnd.Next(1,10);
    for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
    {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(26 * rnd.NextDouble() + 65)) ;
            if(ch=='[' || ch==']')
                    j--;
            else
                    builder.Append(ch); 
    }
    builder.Append("\"");
    //...
}
strXml += builder.ToString();
```